# Django MultiWidget and field labels

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a requirement for a Django form that contains 3 `forms.Textarea` which are compressed into a single `models.TextField` compatible value. For this, I've subclassed both `forms.MultiValueField` and `forms.MultiWidget`. My problem is in trying to identify where and how to add labels to the widget's `textarea` inputs.

What I am currently doing is passing in the label value as an `attr` to the widget's subwidgets:

```python
class ContentWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    template_name = 'content_widget.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            forms.Textarea({'label': 'A'}),
            forms.Textarea({'label': 'B'}),
            forms.Textarea({'label': 'C'}),
        )
        super().__init__(widgets, attrs)
```

This lets me keep the `content_widget.html` pretty concise:

```
{% for subwidget in widget.subwidgets %}
  <label for="{{ subwidget.attrs.id }}">{{ subwidget.attrs.label }}</label>
  {% include subwidget.template_name with widget=subwidget %}
  <br />
{% endfor %}
```

But this also adds the `label` attr to each html element, which feels a bit hacky:

```html
<textarea name="content_0" cols="40" rows="10" label="A" required="" id="id_content_0"></textarea>
```

Another option is to explicitly include it in a more long-form version of the template:

```
<label for="{{ widget.subwidgets.0.attrs.id }}">A</label>
{% include widget.subwidgets.0.template_name with widget=subwidget %}
...
```

However, for form elements in general, the label is assigned to the *field*, but I can't find a way for the widget to access them from the `MultiValueField` instance if I define them there:

```python
class ContentField(forms.MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.CharField(label="A"),
            forms.CharField(label="B"),
            forms.CharField(label="C"),
        )
        super().__init__(fields, require_all_fields=False, **kwargs)
```

My concern is both that this makes the code harder to maintain and that this indicates I've missed something obvious here. My question is if there's a more consistent approach.

Comment: This is exactly my current issue (except my fields are created dynamically, so the 'long-form' option is not available to me).  Did you ever reach a satisfactory resolution?  I'm on the verge of ditching `MultiWidget` altogether.

Comment: @simon i ended up switching to vue for the front end and using django as an api layer

Comment: Yeah, I can see that possibility in this project's future...  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I have found to do something similar is adding the placeholder attribute

```py
class TimedeltaWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, fields, attrs=None, *args, **kwargs):
        fields[0].widget.attrs={'placeholder': _('Days')}
        fields[1].widget.attrs={'placeholder': _('Hours')}
        fields[2].widget.attrs={'placeholder': _('Minutes')}
        fields[3].widget.attrs={'placeholder': _('Seconds')}
        widgets = (fields[0].widget, fields[1].widget, fields[2].widget, fields[3].widget, )
        super(TimedeltaWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)
```

Here the result:

[image: image of result]